# how to create object by read file ( cpp and header ) in c++

Tags: c++, instance

I want to create an object by reading a file that contains class declarations and definitions(one file or cpp, header).  The object is the type of class read.  And the class inherits the class already defined in the program.
is it enable?

Comment: please illustrate with some code, currently it is not completely clear what you want to do

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand what you are trying to explain. Can your write bit more details or share code snippet?